# How to embed DocuSign console UI into React app

Tags: reactjs, docusignapi

I am trying to embedd DocuSign envelope sending console into my react application. Is there any API to integrate this. I am unable to find solution from past 2 days. If anyone implemented this please guide me.
Thanks in advance

I have tried below blog

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/embed-ui/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't have a server component and want to make the API calls from your React app from the client-side (from the browser).

You will need to configure [CORS](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/cors-here) for your application. This is required to make API calls from the browser.

You can [see a working example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/poZXGNB)

Here is the codePen code:

```
// Copyright © 2022 DocuSign, Inc.
// License: MIT Open Source https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

import {
    CallApi,
    ImplicitGrant,
    UserInfo
    // View the source at https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/LYBKqxb
} from "https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/LYBKqxb.js";
import {
    msg,
    htmlMsg,
    adjustRows,
    errMsg,
    workingUpdate,
    usingHttps
    // View the source at https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/QWBXYzX
} from "https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/QWBXYzX.js";

$(function () {
    // Set basic variables
    const dsReturnUrl = "https://docusign.github.io/jsfiddleDsResponse.html";
    const logLevel = 0; // 0 is terse; 9 is verbose
    let signingCeremonyWindow = null;

    // Example settings
    const docUrl = "https://docusign.github.io/examples/docs/anchorfields.pdf";
    const docViewUrl =
        "https://docusign.github.io/examples/docs/anchorfields_view.pdf";

    debugger; // uncomment with debugger open to find the right JS file.

    /*
     * The doit function is the example that is triggered by the
     * button. The user is already logged in (we have an access token).
     */
    let doit = async function doitf(event) {
        $("#doit").addClass("hide");
        if (!checkToken()) {
            // Check that we have a valid token
            return;
        }
        workingUpdate(true);
        const signer = {
            name: data.userInfo.name,
            email: data.userInfo.email,
            clientUserId: 1000
        };
        const envelopeId = await createEnvelope(signer);
        if (envelopeId) {
            msg(`Envelope ${envelopeId} created.`);
            await embeddedSigningCeremony({
                envelopeId: envelopeId,
                signer: signer
            });
        }
        $("#doit").removeClass("hide");
        workingUpdate(false);
    };
    doit = doit.bind(this);

    /*
     *  Create the envelope by completely specifying the envelope.
     *  Often the recommended alternative is to first create a template
     *  on the DocuSign platform, then reference the template when
     *  creating the envelope. See the other examples...
     */
    async function createEnvelope({ name, email, clientUserId }) {
        const docB64 = await data.callApi.getDocB64(docUrl); // fetch a document

        const req = {
            emailSubject: "Please sign the attached document",
            status: "sent",
            customFields: {
                listCustomFields: [
                    {
                        name: "Envelope list custom field 1",
                        show: "true",
                        value: "value 1"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Envelope list custom field 2",
                        show: "true",
                        value: "value 2"
                    }
                ],
                textCustomFields: [
                    {
                        name: "Envelope text custom field 1",
                        show: "true",
                        value: "value 1"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Envelope text custom field 2",
                        show: "true",
                        value: "value 2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            documents: [
                {
                    name: "Example document",
                    documentBase64: docB64,
                    fileExtension: "pdf",
                    documentId: "1",
                    documentFields: [
                        {
                            name: "doc field 1",
                            value: "val 1"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "doc field 2",
                            value: "val 2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            recipients: {
                signers: [
                    {
                        email: email,
                        name: name,
                        clientUserId: clientUserId,
                        customFields: ["field1: value 1", "field2: value 2"],
                        recipientId: "1",
                        tabs: {
                            signHereTabs: [
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "20",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels"
                                }
                            ],
                            checkboxTabs: [
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "180",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels",
                                    tabLabel: "checkbox 1",
                                    tabGroupLabels: ["checkbox group"]
                                },
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "180",
                                    anchorYOffset: "20",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels",
                                    tabLabel: "checkbox 2",
                                    tabGroupLabels: ["checkbox group"]
                                }
                            ],
                            tabGroups: [
                                {
                                    groupLabel: "checkbox group",
                                    groupRule: "SelectExactly",
                                    minimumRequired: "1",
                                    maximumAllowed: "1",
                                    validationMessage:
                                        "Please check one option",
                                    tabScope: "document",
                                    pageNumber: "1",
                                    documentId: "1"
                                }
                            ],
                            textTabs: [
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "195",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels",
                                    value: "I agree with license 1",
                                    locked: "true",
                                    font: "Helvetica",
                                    fontSize: "Size12",
                                    bold: "true"
                                },
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "195",
                                    anchorYOffset: "20",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels",
                                    value: "I agree with license 2",
                                    locked: "true",
                                    font: "Helvetica",
                                    fontSize: "Size12",
                                    bold: "true"
                                },
                                {
                                    anchorString: "/sig1/",
                                    anchorXOffset: "20",
                                    anchorYOffset: "50",
                                    anchorUnits: "pixels",
                                    bold: "true",
                                    font: "Helvetica",
                                    fontSize: "Size14",
                                    fontColor: "NavyBlue",
                                    value:
                                        "Addendum\n‣ Item 1\n‣ Item 2\nThis is a multi-line read-only text field"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        };

        // Make the create envelope API call
        msg(`Creating envelope.`);
        const apiMethod = `/accounts/${data.userInfo.defaultAccount}/envelopes`;
        const httpMethod = "POST";
        const results = await data.callApi.callApiJson({
            apiMethod: apiMethod,
            httpMethod: httpMethod,
            req: req
        });
        if (results === false) {
            errMsg(data.callApi.errMsg);
            return false;
        }
        if (logLevel > 0) {
            htmlMsg(
                `<p>Envelope created. Response:</p><p><pre><code>${JSON.stringify(
                    results,
                    null,
                    4
                )}</code></pre></p>`
            );
        }
        return results.envelopeId;
    }

    /*
     * Create an embedded signing ceremony, open a new tab with it
     */
    async function embeddedSigningCeremony({ envelopeId, signer }) {
        const req = {
            returnUrl: dsReturnUrl,
            authenticationMethod: "None",
            clientUserId: signer.clientUserId,
            email: signer.email,
            userName: signer.name
        };

        // Make the API call
        const apiMethod = `/accounts/${data.userInfo.defaultAccount}/envelopes/${envelopeId}/views/recipient`;
        const httpMethod = "POST";
        const results = await data.callApi.callApiJson({
            apiMethod: apiMethod,
            httpMethod: httpMethod,
            req: req
        });
        if (results === false) {
            errMsg(data.callApi.errMsg);
            return false;
        }
        if (logLevel > 5) {
            htmlMsg(
                `<p>Embedded Signing Ceremony created. Response:</p><p><pre><code>${JSON.stringify(
                    results,
                    null,
                    4
                )}</code></pre></p>`
            );
        }
        msg(`Displaying signing ceremony...`);
        signingCeremonyWindow = window.open(results.url, "_blank");
        if(!signingCeremonyWindow || signingCeremonyWindow.closed || 
           typeof signingCeremonyWindow.closed=='undefined') {
            // popup blocked
            alert ("Please enable the popup window signing ceremony");
        }
        signingCeremonyWindow.focus();
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * signingCeremonyEnded
     * After the signing ceremony ends (in its own tab),
     * the browser tab is redirected to the returnUrl, defined
     * in constant dsReturnUrl.
     * Source:
     * https://github.com/docusign/docusign.github.io/blob/master/jsfiddleDsResponse.html
     *
     * That page runs Javascript to send a message via window.postMessage.
     * The message is tagged with source `dsResponse`.
     * The function messageListener (in mainline section) receives and
     * dispatches the different types of incoming messages.
     * When a dsResponse message is received, this function is called.
     */
    function signingCeremonyEnded(data) {
        if (data.source !== "dsResponse") {
            return; // Sanity check
        }
        signingCeremonyWindow.close(); // close the browser tab
        const href = data.href; // "http://localhost:3000/?event=signing_complete"
        const sections = href.split("?");
        const hasEvents = sections.length === 2;
        const qps = hasEvents ? sections[1].split("&") : [];
        if (!hasEvents) {
            errMsg(`Unexpected signing ceremony response: ${data.href}.`);
            return;
        }
        let msg = `<p><b>Signing Ceremony Response</b><br/>`;
        msg += `<small>Information Security tip: do not make business decisions based on this data since they can be spoofed. Instead, use the API.</small>`;

        qps.forEach((i) => {
            const parts = i.split("=");
            msg += `<br/>Query parameter <b>${parts[0]} = "${parts[1]}"</b>`;
        });
        msg += "</p>";
        htmlMsg(msg);
    }
    
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /* Checks that the access token is still good.
     * Prompts for login if not
     */
    function checkToken() {
        if (data.implicitGrant.checkToken()) {
            // ok
            return true;
        } else {
            // not ok
            $("#login").removeClass("hide");
            $("#doit").addClass("hide");
            // reset everything
            msg("Please login");
        }
    }
    
    /*
     * Receives and dispatches incoming messages
     */
    let messageListener = async function messageListenerf(event) {
        if (!event.data) {
            return;
        }
        const source = event.data.source;
        if (source === "dsResponse") {
            signingCeremonyEnded(event.data);
            return;
        }
        if (source === "oauthResponse" && data.implicitGrant) {
            await implicitGrantMsg(event.data);
            return;
        }
    };
    messageListener = messageListener.bind(this);

    /*
     * Process incoming implicit grant response
     */
    async function implicitGrantMsg(eventData) {
        const oAuthResponse = data.implicitGrant.handleMessage(eventData);
        if (oAuthResponse === "ok") {
            if (await completeLogin()) {
                data.loggedIn();
            }
        } else if (oAuthResponse === "error") {
            $("#login").removeClass("hide");
            const errHtml = `<p class="text-danger">${data.implicitGrant.errMsg}</p>`;
            htmlMsg(errHtml);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Complete login process including
     * Get user information
     * Set up CallApi object
     * update the user
     */
    async function completeLogin() {
        data.userInfo = new UserInfo({
            accessToken: data.implicitGrant.accessToken,
            workingUpdateF: workingUpdate
        });
        const ok = await data.userInfo.getUserInfo();
        if (ok) {
            data.callApi = new CallApi({
                accessToken: data.implicitGrant.accessToken,
                apiBaseUrl: data.userInfo.defaultBaseUrl
            });
            if (logLevel === 0) {
                htmlMsg(
                    `<p><b>${data.userInfo.name}</b><br/>` +
                        `${data.userInfo.email}<br/>` +
                        `${data.userInfo.defaultAccountName}</p>`
                );
            } else {
                htmlMsg(
                    `<p><b>OAuth & UserInfo Results</b><br/>` +
                        `Name: ${data.userInfo.name}` +
                        ` (${data.userInfo.userId})<br/>` +
                        `Email: ${data.userInfo.email}<br/>` +
                        `Default account: ${data.userInfo.defaultAccountName}` +
                        ` (${data.userInfo.defaultAccount})<br/>` +
                        `Base URL: ${data.userInfo.defaultBaseUrl}</p>`
                );
            }
        } else {
            // Did not complete the login
            $("#login").removeClass("hide");
            const errHtml = `<p class="text-danger">${data.userInfo.errMsg}</p>`;
            htmlMsg(errHtml);
        }
        return ok;
    }

    /*
     * Login button was clicked
     */
    let login = async function loginf(event) {
        $("#login").addClass("hide");
        await data.implicitGrant.login();
    };
    login = login.bind(this);

    // Mainline
    let data = {
        implicitGrant: null,
        userInfo: null,
        callApi: null,
        loggedIn: () => $("#doit").removeClass("hide")
    };

    // The mainline
    if (usingHttps()) {
        adjustRows();
        data.implicitGrant = new ImplicitGrant({
            workingUpdateF: workingUpdate
        });

        window.addEventListener("message", messageListener);
        $("#btnOauth").click(login);
        $("#btnDoit").click(doit);
    }
});



  [1]: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/single-page-applications-cors/
  [2]: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-cors-app-embedded/
```

Comment: Hi Inbar, thanks for quick response. I have implemented this and I am able to successfully send documents for signers. But I also need to embedd DocuSign console UI where users can drag and drop sign options onto the document

Comment: When you say "users can drag and drop" who are these users? senders of envelopes? or signers?

Comment: Senders of envelopes

Comment: ok, we don't have a codePen example showing this, but to do this, you need to use this API - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createsender/

Comment: If you got the other codePen to work, you can can do something similar with the above endpoint, remember that the envelope has to be created first in "draft" state and not be sent so that the sender can drag and drop the tabs using the view you get from the API endpoint above

Comment: Thank you so much Inbar. I am able to get the console URL and embed using iframe